# How to preserve rows with empty (nan) cells when doing groupby on a dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains four columns: ["Artist", "Album", "Title", "Point"] where the first three columns identify a song, and the fourth is a score. Each song may appear in a list multiple times, and some songs has no album information, which is a nan value in the corresponding cell.
I use the following code to get the sum score for each song:

```
B = A.groupby(['Artist', 'Album', 'Title'])['Point'].sum()
C = B.sort_values(by=['Point'], ascending=[False]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But what I have realized is, that if there is any row with the album information missing (nan), then that row is not appearing in variable B. How can I enforce nan to be a valid distinctive information? If I have the same song twice, once with album and once without, those two should appear as two distinct records after grouping.

Is there a way doing it properly, or do I have to do some pre-treatment of the data by forcing all "nan"s to become empty strings or something?

Comment: I think you can use `ffill` or '`bfill` with `groupby` to fill `nan` values with the album information based on the song. If you can provide input & expected output sample, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a slight adjustment to your suggestion. Instead of turning then `NaN` values into an empty string, you can replace them with `Unknown`. I'll give you a reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Height':[20, 50, 20, 15, 10],
                   'Happy':['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'],
                   'Sex':['M', np.nan, 'M', 'M', 'F']})
print(df)
```

```py
   Height Happy  Sex
0      20    No    M
1      50   Yes  NaN
2      20    No    M
3      15    No    M
4      10   Yes    F
```

```
df.fillna('Unknown').groupby(['Sex', 'Happy'])['Height'].sum()
```

```
Out[8]: 
Sex      Happy
F        Yes      10
M        No       55
Unknown  Yes      50
Name: Height, dtype: int64
```

**In your case**, I'd try:

```
B = A.fillna('Unknown').groupby(['Artist', 'Album', 'Title'])['Point'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

.fillna('N/A')  that will fix the searches. but with more data, there's probably a better solution

```
A['Album'].fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
```

you sums should work then

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do like this.

**Input**

```
   Artist   Album   Point
0   AC1     A       1
1   AC2     B       2
2   AC1     NaN     3
3   AC4     A       4
4   AC5     C       5
```

```
a = df.groupby(['Artist'])['Album'].ffill()
df.groupby(['Artist', a ])['Point'].sum().reset_index(name='Points')
```

**output**

```
 Artist     Album   Points
0   AC1     A       4
1   AC2     B       2
2   AC4     A       4
3   AC5     C       5
```

This code is probably what you can use

```
df['Album'] = df['Album'].astype(str)
df.groupby(['Artist','Album'])['Point'].sum().reset_index(name='Points')
```

**output**

```
  Artist    Album   Points
0   AC1     A       1
1   AC1     nan     3
2   AC2     B       2
3   AC4     A       4
4   AC5     C       5
```